# Could we get a tighter layout for questions and answers when moderator tools are visible?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, moderator-tools, organization

Currently, when moderator tools are visible it pushes down the comments section:

[image: Current beta site answer layout]

That's a lot of unused white space--kind of unsightly and it makes you scroll further for comments.

Could we get a tighter layout like this?

[image: Proposed beta site answer layout]

Edited to note that this also applies to questions, such as [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/influences-from-outside-the-observable-universe-explaining-dark-energy-and-expan).

This doesn't seem to have been addressed in the recent design overhaul.

**UPDATE 8/27/2020**: This still hasn't been fixed in the latest post formatting update, though the unsightly new line spacing makes it less noticeable.

Comment: If it helps, it looks like adding "grid-row: span 2" to .votecell would make this happen without borking anything else in the design--haven't extensively tested, though.

Comment: The userscript that preceded the built-in mod tools behaved as you're requesting, and I never noticed problems in the ~2 years I used it.  The tools in the margin won't overlap the comment text, so it's safe to move the comments up.

Answer (score -1):

We just changed this from [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). We were able to repro the issue ([example](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27228/why-would-a-significant-non-zero-angle-of-attack-be-an-advantage-during-1st-stag/27284#27284)), but since this only happens when the question or answer is pretty short, we decided not to prioritize this fix. It doesn't fit in with the main priorities on our [roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/23/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q2-2021/).

Comment: Instead of a link to an answer, could you take a screenshot of how the layout appears to you? Us non-diamond mortals can't see what you can see.

Comment: I know it's a pretty minor impact, but it's also a pretty minor change. Will there ever be a point where this might be considered? Or does `declined` mean "won't fix" in this case?

Comment: @called2voyage "Declined" has recently been used for "we'll fix this, but not in the near term, and we have no real plans to put this on our backlog quite yet." It's not a death sentence, so to speak, for bug fixes/feature requests, but it does mean that it may take longer than 6-8 weeks. ;)

Comment: Isn't this the reason why [meta-tag:status-deferred] exists? We will do it, just not yet.