# Reduce whitespace between short posts and their comment section

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, answers, moderator-tools

For ♦ moderators, the vote section contains some additional links (to the flag history, and to show deleted comments). For short answers like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386466/295232), this causes unnecessary whitespace between the answer and its comments. Giving the vote section `rowspan=2` or whatever the `div` equivalent is would solve this problem.

[image]

I guess this would extend to questions as well, but those have a line with tags, which makes this situation less apparent. And I could solve it myself by providing longer answers, but there are definitely cases where three lines are sufficient...

Comment: I don't disagree but I'm also preeeeety sure there's an existing request for this... just not sure whether it's a question or an answer... Hmmmm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could we get a tighter layout for questions and answers when moderator tools are visible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312866/could-we-get-a-tighter-layout-for-questions-and-answers-when-moderator-tools-are) (cc @Cat, it could also use being moved to status-deferred instead of declined based on the answer)